# How to remove white lines when using Google Maps API on iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-maps-api-3

I'm using custom styling to create a blue map using Google Maps API V3.

[image: example when scrolling on iPad]

It renders fine across different browsers on a desktop, but when I view it on an iPad there is a vertical white line present. Further, when scrolling there's a horizontal line, as shown in the photo above.

Here is a JSFiddle example of my code in action.

```
  var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: styles
        };
```

[JSFiddle of custom colour styling](http://jsfiddle.net/xrHar/2/)

Is there a way to remove or smooth out these lines?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to ignore all webkit's specific prefix styling.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Tested on *iPad* within *iOS Simulator*, `running iOS 7.1`: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/xrHar/91/

Safari's documentation on [-webkit-appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-appearance)

Comment: Interestingly since I posted this problem over a year ago Google Maps has changed and the white lines appear on my desktop computer as well. The above fix doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: Well, too bad. I opened my fiddle on an iPad, and it was fixed there... When you say desktop computer, what system would that be and what browser?